# Verificar se uma letra existe na string c++

Tags: c++, string, funções

Estou com problemas na minha função que faz a verificação da existência de uma letra específica em uma string (não sei muito sobre ponteiros só usei pois a minha outra função não estava retornando a string se não fosse por ponteiro.)

Como eu declarei minha string dentro da class:

```
char *nome[tamanho];
```

Minha função:

```
int Charclass::verificar_letra_existente(){
char *a;
int i;
int valorretornado;

printf("digite uma letra:\n");

scanf("%c",*a);

for(i=0;i<tamanho;i++)
{
  if(*nome[i]==*a){
    printf("ACHAMOS A LETRA NA STRING, ESTA NA POSICAO:");
    return i;
  }
}
printf("NAO ACHAMOS UMA LETRA NA STRING :\n");
}
```

Comment: Quais foram os erros que apareceram?

Comment: ele pede a letra para verificar a string, quando eu digito ele fecha o programa, ele nem verificar se existe na string. @v.Santos

Comment: `tamanho` é uma constante global? Com qual valor você está inicializando ela? Edita a sua pergunta para colocar também, no mínimo, o construtor da classe `charClass`. Ajudaria também se você colocasse o trecho em que você está instanciando o objeto dessa classe e o trecho que você está invocando o método `verificar_letra_existente()` . @Vitor.

Comment: como eu tinha dito eu não sei mexer com ponteiros, meu professor falou pra usar  ponteiros só na função que retorna string, sendo assim não vou precisr mais do código, muito obrigado @v.Santos

Comment: formate o código com indentação e espaços, senão fica mais difícil ainda de entender...dei uma arrumada na formatação para ficar melhorzinho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse código não tem nada de C++, tirando a declaração da função.
Você cometeu vários erros básicos. Corrigi abaixo, mas não testei o funcionamento.

```
int Charclass::verificar_letra_existente() {
  // char *a; // <-----
  char a;
  int i;
  int valorretornado;

  printf("digite uma letra:\n");

  // scanf("%c", *a); // <---
  scanf(" %c", &a);

  for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
  {
    // if (*nome[i] == *a) { // <--- onde e' que foi declarado "nome" ???
    if (nome[i] == a) { // <--- onde e' que foi declarado "nome" ???
      printf("ACHAMOS A LETRA NA STRING, ESTA NA POSICAO:");
      return i;
    }
  }

  printf("NAO ACHAMOS UMA LETRA NA STRING :\n");
}
```

Comment: se você diz que o código não está em c++ pelo fato de ter scanf e printf? você está equivocado, estou dentro de uma classe então sim estou em c++. (só não deixei explicado na pergunta para não ficar enormeee =p)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, assim está funcionando corretamente =)

Comment: eu não sei usar ponteiros por isso deixei logo claro, vou esperar um pouco para trabalhar com ponteiros.